# Nested ES6 generator crashes or errors in Safari when console opened or closed?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, safari, safari-web-inspector, es6-generator

Writing a generator that yield*s inside another generator every rAF (in order to do some event sequences on various conditions and timings), normally it works fine.
But when I open or close the console in Safari, the generator stops working (or worse).

It either crashes the browser or throws the error: 
"TypeError: yield* subGenerator is not a function. (In 'yield* subGenerator()', 'yield* subGenerator' is undefined)"

I've looked around a bunch but I can't find related info. I've tried assigning the subgenerator to a var, and logging the related objects to turn up extra info, but didn't find any hints.

```js
    mainGenerator = function*() {
      while (true) {
        yield* subGenerator()
      }
    }
    
    subGenerator = function*() {
      while (true) {
        yield
      }
    }
    
    update = function() {
      generatey.next()
      window.requestAnimationFrame(update.bind(this));
    
    }
    var generatey = mainGenerator();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update.bind(this));
```

[JSFiddle HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/hvofwk0z/](https://jsfiddle.net/hvofwk0z/)

Run, THEN open (or close) console to see the generator will stop, sometimes with an error, sometimes crashing the tab.

Not being able to open/close the console without breaking the page is making debugging difficult.

Is there something I'm missing? Am I making a mistake here somewhere? Or is this a universal es6 bug?

Comment: I can't reproduce on Opera 57, FF 56, nor Chrome 71, on Win 10. No errors at all, tab remains responsive.

Comment: Can’t reproduce that in current Firefox, Chrome 71. Which browser versions are you using? Are you close to being out of memory? If you use `setTimeout(…, 0)` instead of `requestAnimationFrame(…)`, does it start working?

Comment: Right, thank you for checking, it appears the repro case only fails in Safari! I'll investigate what difference is making Chrome and FF work... Plenty of memory. The issue persists when using setTimeout.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox work fine, there was an unrelated mistake my project's subGenerator. However, Safari still crashes.

Comment: Which version of Safari? Definitely starting to sound like a browser bug.

Comment: 12.0.2. Yeah I think you're right. I sent a report to Apple just in case.